# open link in a video player codova

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk, apache-cordova

Hello I have a video link in my cordova app like this:

```
<a href="video link">Play Video</a>
```

Could I make that when I press the link in android open for example Vlc video player that I have installed in my phone?

Comment: jus try out some video player plugin like https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer which does the job for you easily. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks friend but I need to call a specific player because it´s a streaming video

Comment: try using fileopener2 plugin then